# how to create user rules for function like CRUD using PHP in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have made a user rules for menu. so every user only can see the menu they have not all, but now I need to creating user rules for each function like CRUD in codeigniter, so the user cannot do any function without setting the function they need in set rules of CRUD functions. may someone can help me for the guidline how to creating set rules for function like CRUD, so from the function we can choose what kind of function user can use.

[I'm try to create like this pic, so we can choose the function that user can use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOqHX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to have every user to have a role, correct? If I'm an administrator, I can create,delete and update. If I'm just an ordinary user, all I can do is just view the data. When you create a user on the database, have a field where you specify if he is an Admin or a User. Then when a user login, give them a $_SESSION['AccountType']. You have to manipulate the page according to the account type.

Comment: yes every user have a role. I think maybe I can manipulate the page of users with creating different body for each user account type, thank you for the answer.

Comment: how if i want to create a check box?. so we can choose the function user can have. I ever try using check box but it doesn't work, maybe you can give me some example? thank you

Comment: Well you are talking about custom user privileges and want to assign the privileges to users yourself from the interface and then let you user perform those tasks as per the privileges you have assigned . is that it?